# Is there a short form to concat a string with another one into the same variable in dart?

Tags: string, dart, concatenation

I want to build a string like this:

```
String mainString = "Hello, \n";
mainString = mainString + "World";
print(mainstring);
```

Is there a way to do this in dart without having to repeat the variable? Example of what I want done in perl:

```
my $main_string = "Hello, \n";
$main_string .= "World";
print($main_string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write you code like this instead which are shorter:

```
void main() {
  String mainString = "Hello, \n";
  mainString += "World";
  print(mainString);
}
```

If you are going to concatenating a lot of strings (like e.g. in a loop) it is much more efficient to use [StringBuffer](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/StringBuffer-class.html) to append the strings and then create the `String` object from the `StringBuffer` like:

```
void main() {
  final sb = StringBuffer("Hello, \n");
  sb.write("World");
  print(sb.toString());
}
```

The reason is by using the `StringBuffer` we don't need to create a new `String` object each time we concatenating a String to it.

Comment: Is there documentation for `+=`? I could not see it mentioned in the [String class](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.1/dart-core/String-class.html#operators) documentation.

Comment: The reason of no mention in the documentation is that you cannot override `+=` in Dart since it will always be defined as: `a = a + b`. The same for `-=`,`/=` and `*=` (and more which you can find in the spec). There are very little about it here: https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assignment-operators . For a (very) more technical description you can read about compoundAssignmentOperator in the spec: https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf

Comment: And the reason for why this operation cannot be overridden is so the language are consistent with other similar languages (e.g. Java and C#). It could be very confusion for developers if `a += b` did not always mean `a = a + b`.